# Does loading a https:// website via UIWebView.loadRequest() in Xcode count as encryption when submitting to AppStore?

Tags: swift, xcode, encryption, uiwebview, app-store-connect

Would requesting a web page (GET only) in this way be considered using non-exempt encryption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

> Typically, the use of encryption that’s built into the operating system—for example, when your app makes HTTPS connections using URLSession—is exempt from export documentation upload requirements, whereas the use of proprietary encryption is not.

[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/complying_with_encryption_export_regulations)